# Proving the negative of a Dedekind cut is itself a Dedekind cut

Tags: real-analysis

Given a Dedekind cut $x=A|B$, Define $-x$ as $C|D$, where $C$ consists of the negatives $r=-b$ of the elements $b\in B$ such that $b>b'$ for some $b'\in B$ and $D$ is the complement of $\mathbb{Q}-C$. Verify that $-x$ is a Dedekind cut.

I know a Dedekind cut $A|B$ must have the properties

1) $A\cup B=\mathbb{Q}, A\ne \emptyset, B\ne \emptyset,$ and $A\cap B= \emptyset$

2) If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $a<b$

3) A has no largest element.

My approach would be to show that $-x$ has each of these properties. However, I feel there must me a more efficient method to prove $-x$ is indeed a Dedekind cut. There is a given hint i.e. First prove that if $X|Y$ is a Dedekind cut, $y\in Y$, and $z$ is a rational number such that $y\le z$, then $z\in Y$. I don't see how this hint is relevant, this is what leads me to believe I am going in the wrong direction. So how is it that I prove $-x$ is a Dedekind cut?

Comment: I suspect that the hint was given partly to make sure that you’re visualizing Dedekind cuts correctly, and that you are intended simply to verify that $C|D$ has the required properties. However, the hint actually is useful in proving that $C\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: So I am correct in my approach to show that $-x$ has all the properties of a Dedekind cut?

Comment: Yes, you are. I don't see see any clever shortcut at the moment.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the input!